# bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that can do many mathematical operations and has many functions about math for me and my friend. One of those functions is a plot command.

I want this function to receive a mathematical function and a range for the values of x. My code works properly if I run it on a separate python file. Here is the code :

```
def plot(f, xrange):

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) #setup the x and y axis
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')


    _x = np.arange(-xrange, -0.001, 0.001) + np.arange(0.001, xrange, 0.001) #No zero in the interval to plot inverse/rational functions

    try:
        _y = [eval(f) for x in _x]

    except:
        _x = np.arange(0.001, xrange, 0.001) #Avoid 0 and negative numbers to plot some functions that are not defined on negative numbers
        _y = [eval(f) for x in _x]

    plt.plot(_x, _y)
    plt.show()
```

And if i run :

```
plot('1/x', 1)
```

where f is `1/x` and `xrange` is 1 i get my plot : [1/x with x from -1 to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALyyT.png)

However, when I want to implement the function on my real bot code (here's the code, it's just slightly different):

```
@client.command()
async def plot(ctx, f, xrange):

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')


    x1 = np.arange(-xrange, -0.001, 0.001)
    x2 = np.arange(0.001, xrange, 0.001)

    _x = np.add(x1,x2)

    try:
        _y = [eval(f) for x in _x]

    except:
        _x = np.arange(0.001, xrange, 0.001)
        _y = [eval(f) for x in _x]

    plt.plot(_x, _y)
    plt.title(f'{ctx.message.author}\'s Graph') #The discord part
    plt.savefig(fname='plot')
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('plot.png'))
    os.remove('plot.png')
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "...\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "...\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError:
Command raised an exception:
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Strangely, it works in the first code but not in the second, i think that there is an issue with the -xrange but xrange is supposed to be a float so i should be able to put a minus sign in front of it

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i included it, hope it helps

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This means that an interested reader should be able to take your posted code, run it, and get the exact same error message as you. As it is, your code uses all sorts of variables such as `xrange` whose definition lies in code which you do not show. Your error message suggests that some of those variables do not contain the sort of values that you think they contain.

Comment: There is a problem with the indentation of the code - there should be an extra indentation level after `def plot(ctx, f, xrange):`

Comment: The traceback says you used `-` on a string instead of using it on a number; it's not clear on which line the error happened, but I'm guessing it's because of `-xrange` in `np.arange(-xrange, -0.001, 0.001)`. Can you show what `xrange` is and explain what you wanted to do with that line?

Comment: @Stef So i explained the purpose of xrange, you said that the error could be because of the -xrange but i have the same problem if i add the line float(xrange) before

Comment: @Aurel271 Have you tried with `plt.savefig('plot.png')` instead of `plt.savefig('plot')`?

Comment: Also can you please add `print('so far so good')` just before `await ctx.send(file=discord.File('plot.png'))` to make sure the exception doesn't happen before that?

Comment: @Stef I tried to print so 'so far so good' but as expected the exception happens before. I'm using visual studio and the highlighted line of code is the line with the sum of the two np.arange. Do you know if there is any way to exclude some specific values of a numpy arange ? I think that it would solve the problem because i wouldn't have to add together the 2 parts of the interval on which i want to evaluate f(x)

Comment: @Stef Alright my bad, i did some tests and i was wrong, im pretty sure that the problem comes from the -xrange, ill edit my post

Comment: In your function, you expect the received `xrange` to be an integer. When you call the function locally, it is an integer, because that is how you wrote the code explicitly. When you call the function by passing data from the Discord bot, it is a string, because the Discord bot received text data from Discord.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks, i fixed it, it was dumb but i was so convinced that the problem was because of the arange that i didn't thought about it. Now it works perfectly, thanks a lot

Comment: @Stef I finally fixed it and i feel dumb but thanks a lot, you really helped me and i really appreciate it. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that produces your error:

```
In [43]: -'astring'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-43-e14f33b3dabb>", line 1, in <module>
    -'astring'
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

It's hard to tell from the traceback where it's happening.  But clearly some variable or argument is string, when it really should be a number.

It could be happening in:

```
x1 = np.arange(-xrange, -0.001, 0.001)
```

if `xrange` is a string.  That's an argument to the function, so we don't know what it is.